# Matching and replacing with for loops

Tags: r, matrix

Having issues with a for loop.

I am trying to take elements a b c d from each pathway (pathway matrix) and match them to expression data (expression matrix) and put them into a new matrix which look similar to pathway matrix but now contains the elements from expression matrix.

I am trying to acheve this final matrix outcome.

```
a <- c("pathway","1","4","7","pathway-2","1","e","g","pathway-3","4","g","h")
pathway<-matrix(a,3,4, byrow=T)
```

The code will be easier to understand than my wording I hope.

```
a <- c("pathway","b","c","d","pathway-2","b","e","g","pathway-3","c","g","h")
pathway<-matrix(a,3,4, byrow=T)

b <- c("b",1,"c",4,"d",7)
expression<-matrix(b,3,2, byrow=T)

new<-matrix("a",3,4)
new[1:3,1]<-pathway[,1]

for (x in 1:nrow(expression)){
  for (y in 1:ncol(pathway)){
    if(expression[x,1]==pathway[x,y]){
      new[x,y]<-expression[x,2]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. We match each column of `pathway[,-1]` with the `expression[,1]` matrix, and use the resulting matrix as index for the values from `expression[,2]`. The ones not found return `NA` so we index them and replace them from the original matrix. Then `cbind` as usual to get desired matrix.

```
new_m <- apply(pathway[, -1], 2, function(i) expression[,2][match(i, expression[,1])])
new_m[which(is.na(new_m))] <- pathway[,-1][which(is.na(new_m))]
cbind(pathway[,1], new_m)
#     [,1]        [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,] "pathway"   "1"  "4"  "7" 
#[2,] "pathway-2" "1"  "e"  "g" 
#[3,] "pathway-3" "4"  "g"  "h"
```

Comment: Excellent solution.....seems like you can avoid `cbind` with a `new_m[, -1] <- apply(pathway[, -1], ......)`.

Comment: Thank you... So why doesn't the loop work? can't this be done with a loop? I know apply is a loop but I mean for loop.... The things is that this is a snippet of the actual data... and there are 2000 columns in real pathway data frame...

Comment: I guess this should still work regardless of number of columns

Comment: @ComputerNoob, Yes. As long as the first column is always going to be excluded, then it will work for any number of columns.

Comment: @Sotos Can you tell me why my loop is not working... This is really bothering me